# VB.NET string.contains using wildcards

Tags: string, vb.net, contains

I Noticed that in a loop inside treeview items , when i am using string.contains method parallel with a textbox that i enter the search string in order to highlight finded nondes , i cant use any wildcard like * or % ... is there any other way to use wildcards ?

What i have tried is having  multiple textboxes ex. textbox_x, textbox_y and multiple string.contains in the code string.contains(x) or string.contains(y) but that obviusly doesnt meet my needs because the user may want to use numerous wildcard combinations..

Comment: Why are you randomly trying stuff instead of reading the documentation? If `String.Contains` supported wildcards then it would be specified there. The fact that there is no mention of it there would have told that it's not supported and thus trying anything would be a waste of time.

Comment: There are multiple alternatives so there is no one good answer, which means that your question is too broad/vague for SO. You need to do some research for yourself to find out where and how wildcards are supported, make your best attempt and then post back with all the specific details if you encounter an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple function that allows the use of `*` as jokers at any position
(using regex, here also set to case-insensitive).

```
Public Shared Function TestSimplePattern(value As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) Then Return False
    Dim parts = pattern.Split("*")
    Dim rxPattern = String.Join(".*?", parts.Select(Function(item) Regex.Escape(item)).ToArray)
    rxPattern = "^" & rxPattern & "$"
    Return Regex.IsMatch(value, rxPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
End Function
```

Can be used like this:

```
TestSimplePattern("VB.NET string.contains using wildcards", "*wildcards") ' true
TestSimplePattern("VB.NET string.contains using wildcards", "*string*using*") ' true
TestSimplePattern("VB.NET string.contains using wildcards", "*string*using") ' false
```